# Is it valid to put predicted data into training data set?

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose for K nearest neighbor algorithm, we have a original training data set `x1,x2,...,xn` and we test `p1`. After classification of `p1`, we put `p1` into training data set.

The newest training data set now is `{x1,x2,....,xn,p1}` and we test `p2`... and so on.

I think the above is quite counter intuitive that we used "fake" data to train our program. But i cannot think any proof/reason to say why we cannot use the "fake" data.

Comment: you can use what you want. But will it make sense, is the question. When using predicted p1 as training, you are reinforcing that what model learned is true. And adding more and more predictions in dataset will only reinforce it. But sadly, that will be far from the real training data. And your model will perform poorly on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only make the model more biased toward the original training set by updating the boundary between classes using its own prediction. In addition, adding more observations to your training set without offering any ground truth knowledge only makes the feature space more dense and reduces the impact of K which can lead to higher chance of over-fitting.